# Show the middle page of pageViewController num first when app loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

i have 3 ViewControllers added to a UIPageViewContoller Everything works fine 
but my code here is showing the first view or number 0 looking like a walkthrough from 0 to 2 I want the view controller first to lunch is number 1 that's mean the middle one

```
class PageController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource  {

    lazy var viewControllerlist: [UIViewController] = {

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let V1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "M")
        let V2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "N")
        let V3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "S")

        return[V1, V2, V3]

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        if let firstViewController = viewControllerlist.first {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerlist.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerlist.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

        return viewControllerlist[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerlist.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1
        guard viewControllerlist.count != nextIndex else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerlist.count > nextIndex else {return nil}

        return viewControllerlist[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

Comment: Then why are saying `if let firstViewController = viewControllerlist.first` if what you want is the _second_ one? It makes no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
 let middle = viewControllerlist[1]
 self.setViewControllers([middle], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it doesn't work " Type 'UIViewController' has no subscript members "

Comment: nothing changed more errors

Comment: change if let in **viewDidLoad** to answer

Comment: @Sh_Khan You just answered this same question a few days ago. Instead of reposting the same answer, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: thank you this method just worked as it's should be simple and clear and short

Comment: @rmaddy you have a strong memory , but i confused that even that answer also not works with him as you see alot of edits until solved , Ok I will ......